# How to calculate complexity if a code contains multiple n complexity loops?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I am a bit confused on the topic of calculating complexity. 
I know about Big O and also how to calculate the complexity of loops (nested also). 
 
Suppose I have a program with 3 loops running from 1 to n

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{ 
cout << i ; 
}
```

Now if I ran my CPP code having 3 for loops, will it take 3*n time? 
 
Will the CPP compiler run all the 3 loops at the same time or will do it one after another? 
I am very confused on this topic. Please help!

Comment: I can see only one loop in your code.

Comment: for loops one after the another calculated to `O(m * n)` which is approx `O(n)`. nested loops are diffrent, 2 nested loops calculated to `O(n^2)`. but compilers and optimisers today are very smart! and they can predict the out come of for loop (if it posible) and omit the for loop for performance.

Comment: no offense, but you are contradicting yourself. If you knew how big-O notation works you would know that `O(m *n) == O(n)`  (as long as `m` does not depend on `n`)

Comment: I think that what OP does not understand is that in `O` notation is not the constants that matter, but rather _the shape of the time curve_. `O(1000*n)` and `O(2*n)` for the same input will have vastly different run times, but both algorithms are _linear_. When we think about `O`, we are interested into how time would scale with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to calculate complexity if a code contains multiple n complexity loops?

To understand Big-O notation and *asymptotic* complexity, it can be useful to resort at least to semi-formal notation.

Consider the problem of finding and *upper* bound on the asymptotic time complexity a function `f(n)` based on the growth of `n`.

To our help, lets loosely define a function or algorithm `f` being in `O(g(n))` (to be picky, `O(g(n))` being a *set of functions*, hence `f ∈ O(...)`, rather than the commonly misused `f(n) ∈ O(...)`) as follows:

> If a function `f` is *in* `O(g(n))`, then `c · g(n)` is an upper
>   bound on `f(n)`, for some non-negative constant `c` such that `f(n) ≤ c · g(n)`
>   holds, **for sufficiently large `n`** (i.e. , `n ≥ n0` for some constant
>   `n0`).

Hence, to show that `f ∈ O(g(n))`, we need to find a set of (non-negative) constants `(c, n0)` that fulfils

```
f(n) ≤ c · g(n), for all n ≥ n0,                                (+)
```

Let's consider your actual problem

```
void foo(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
}
```

and for analyzing the asymptotic behaviour of `foo` based on growth on `n`, consider `std::cout << i << "\n";` as our *basic operation*. Thus, based on this definition, `foo` contains `3 * n` basic operations, and we may consider `foo` mathematically as

```
f(n) = 3 * n.
```

Now, we need to find a `g(n)` and *some* set of constants `c` and `n0` such that `(+)` holds. For this particular analysis this is nearly trivial; insert `f(n)` as above in `(+)` and let `g(n) = n`:

```
3 * n ≤ c · g(n), for all n ≥ n0, [let g(n) = n]

3 * n ≤ c · n, for all n ≥ n0,    [choose c = 3]

3 * n ≤ 3 · n, for all n ≥ n0.
```

The latter holds for any valid `n`, and we may arbitrarily choose `n0 = 0`. Thus, as per our definition above of a function `f` being in `O(g(n))`, we have showed that `f` is in `O(n)`.

It is apparent that even if we multiply the loop in `foo` a multiple of times, as long as this multiple is *constant* (and not dependent on `n` itself), we can always find a degenerate number of constants `c` and `n0` that will fulfill `(+)` for `g(n) = n`, thus showing that the function `f` describing the number of basic operations in `foo` based on `n` is upper bounded by linear growth.

> Now if I ran my CPP code having 3 for loops, will it take 3*n time?

However, it is essential to understand that Big-O notation describes the upper bound on the asymptotic behaviour of a mathematically described algorithm, or e.g. of programmatically implemented function that based on the definition of a basic operation can be described as the former. It does not, however, present an accurate description what runtime you may expect of different variations of how to implement a function. Cache locality, parallelism/vectorization, compiler optimizations and hardware intrinsics, inaccuracy in describing the basic operation are just a few of many factors that make the asymptotic complexity disjoint from actual runtime. The linked list data structure is good example of one where asymptotic analysis is not likely to give a good view of runtime performance (as loss of cache locality, actual size of lists and so on will likely have a larger effect).

For actual runtime of your algorithms, in case you are hitting a bottle neck, actually measuring on target hardware with product representative compiler and optimization flags is key.

Answer (score 5):

> Now if I ran my CPP code having 3 for loops, will it take 3*n time?

Yes, assuming that the time of each loop iteration is the same, but in Big O notation `O(3*n) == O(n)`, so the complexity is still linear.

> Will the CPP compiler run all the 3 loops at the same time or will do it one after another?

Implicit concurrency requires a compiler to be 100% sure that parallelizing code will not change the outcome. It can be (and it is, see comments) done for simple operations, but `cout << i` is unlikely to be parallelized. It can be optimized in different ways however, e.g. if `n` is known at compile time, compiler could generate the whole string in one go and change the loop into `cout << "123456...";`.
Also, time complexity and concurrency are rather unrelated topics. Code executed on 20 threads will have the same complexity as code executed on one thread, it will just be faster (or not).

Comment: *Compiler has no means of knowing if or how the code could be parallelized, so it will not do anything unless you write code that uses concurrency.* Um, compilers can perform vectorization all the time.  That's a type of parallelization.

Comment: @NathanOliver Do compilers perform vectorization on their own? I thought this only applied to `<algorithm>`, and only if you specify execution policy (but I can be horribly wrong here).

Comment: Compilers can do anything they want, so long as they obey the as-if principle. So a compiler *could* vectorize loops if they could prove that the behavior is unchanged. Whether any compilers currently do that, I couldn't say.

Comment: the CPP compiler makes decisions that affect the behavior of the code. See move constructors vs copy constructors.

Answer (score 3):

> Now if I ran my CPP code having 3 for loops, will it take 3*n time?

Run a thousand loops and still it would be `O(n)`, since while calculating the upper bound time complexity of a function any constant is neglected. So `O(n*m)` will always be O(n) if m doesn't depend on input size.

Also, the compiler won't run them at the same time, but sequentially one after the other(unless multi-threading, ofc). But even then, 3,10 or 1000 loops one after another will probably be considered `O(n)` as per the definition as long as the number of times you loop is not dependent on input size.